# Abrir script na mesma janela

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando um script para juntar strings e abrir um link, porém, ele abre em uma nova guia. Preciso que seja aberto na mesma janela.

```
<form>
<input name="url" type="text" id="cpf"> 
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Acessar" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://site.com.br/' + document.getElementById('cpf').value + '-2/');"
```

Comment: Ao usar `window.open` você está explicitamente dizendo para abrir uma nova janela. Pesquise como fazer para **redirecionar** o usuário.

Answer (score 3):

Para abrir na mesma janela o comando seria:

```html
<form>
<input name="url" type="text" id="cpf"> 
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Acessar" onClick="javascript: window.location.href = 'http://site.com.br/' + document.getElementById('cpf').value + '-2/';"
```

O `window.open` é utilizado para criar uma nova janela, já o `window.location.href` vai indicar para o navegador que o novo endereço deva ser o parâmetro que está sendo informado.

Também pode ser utilizado o `window.location.assign(url)`, conforme referências listadas abaixo.

Referências:
window.open : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/Window/open
window.location : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/location